# Windows: Unzip non .zip file

Tags: windows

How do you unzip a file that does not end in .zip? I tried finding something under the 'open with' option, but wasn't sure where the default unzip application is.

Comment: There may not be one native to Windows..Try 7 ZIP....https://www.7-zip.org/download.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the only difference between your file and other zip files is the file ending, you can simply change it to `.zip`. If it's an archive but it uses another format, you can install 7zip or WinRar for free and unpack it with one of those - they support a wide variety of archive formats, hopefully yours too.